# Links to local files from a SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, custom-list, browser-compatibility, ecb-menu

Ok, I am new to server side development (especially SP development) and I don't know if this is possible but here goes:

I have a custom list which I populate from a local folder on my file system. The folder has many nested folders and files of different formats.

I added a custom ECB menu item for this particular list and I want to be able to open the file (either in the browser or the specific application) when the menu item in the ECB menu for a list item is clicked.

Here's what I have for e.g.:

```
SPUserCustomAction action = list.UserCustomActions.Add();
action.Url = "file:///C://Users//Administrator//Desktop//Dir//file1.txt";
//...
```

But when I click the custom menu item in ECB, I get a browser alert saying: Invalid Page URL.

Am I missing something or is there a particular way of opening files by any other method that can help my issue?

Comment: it gives the same browser alert even after using my server name i.e. file://servername/full_path but in vain

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharePoint 2013 link files from local drive or network drive](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137452/sharepoint-2013-link-files-from-local-drive-or-network-drive)

Answer (score 1):

For Security Reasons, the browser does not allow Code to Access the local file System. Paths to local files require to be given by the user directly (eg. calling it using the Address-Box or selecting it for file upload).

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
action.Url = "file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Dir/file1.txt";
```

Triple slash after the file:, then single slashes (not double) instead of the filesystem backslashes.

Comment: Yes, but still no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried to paste the link in the address bar of your browser?

Comment: yes, it works fine when copied directly in the browser

Comment: have you checked (with a brwoser developer tool F12 or source view), what link is finally rendered in the HTML page and if it differs from the Link you want?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercustomaction.url.aspx), the value inserted in the `URL` property cannot be a path to a local file.

[image]

Instead, a valid value is a `relative path` to the site. Example:

```
newUserCustomAction.set_url('/_layouts/create.aspx');
```

In your case, once you have the list populated with the files, the `url` action should point to the list item, not to the local file. Please try with:

```
action.Url = ”~site/SitePages/Home.aspx?ID={ItemId}&amp;List={ListId}”/
```