# SharePoint 2013 link files from local drive or network drive

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, network-drive

I have been searching, but haven't find any solution, that seems to work for me. What I want to do is to link to file from SharePoint to local/network drive (neither one has worked for me).

What I have tried: `file:///c|/.../file.docx`, `file:///c|/.../file.docx`, `file://\\c:/.../file.docx`, nothing has had any result.

What I get is link, that has destination attached to it, but clicking it has no result.

I need to use this in `Discussion Board` template.

Comment: Have you tried: file:///\\server\share\somedoc.docx. You need 3 forward slashes after file: and the the usual fileshare path i.e. \\sever\sharename

Comment: Tried and result was, that SharePoint turned my URL into following: `file://server/shared/somedoc.docx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a default security feature of most (all?) modern browsers: links of type file:// are not allowed, that's why you don't see any result when you click on them.

There is a workaround that only works in Internet Explorer though. If you add your SharePoint site to the Trusted Sites zone, then file:// links will work.

Comment: Yet I have theoretical question, if User clicks on the link, then does SharePoint need to have access to that file, or only user does. For example, if SharePoint server doesn't see `Network Drives`, but User does.

Comment: when the user clicks on the link, it's the user that needs to have the appropriate permissions to open the file. SharePoint doesn't even know that the user performed a click, it's completely a client-side thing

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could provide a downloadable file "file_link.url" that represents a Windows shortcut:

file_link.url

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=file:///C:
```

If a user downloads the file and opens it, the wanted directory is opened.

(Unfortunately, Firefox might adapt the extension to *.url.download and users cannot simply click on it.)